# Unable to install drivers for Linux Brother DCP-J140W printer

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I'm not able to install the drivers for dcp-j140w brother printer. Brother page for linux shows four drivers, of which i can install only the last two (scanner). Therefore, the first two (printer) it's the main problem.

Another problem, it's that the printer is recognize by my pc, it does print the check impression, but the location file of the printer is empty.

Answer (score 1):

did you follow the instructions here:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn3.html

and after that here:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_prn1a.html

After installing and adding the printer:

note the network, parallel or usb connection settings.

often editing printcap is unnecessary, you just have to edit the connection entry in your GUI printer manager or in cups web based administration 
according to the second link above

by entering
localhost:631/printers 
on your browser.

1. There, you can click on your printer
2. select edit printer on the dropdown list at the top of the printer name
3. Change the connection options as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer hth and guntbert for your editing. I've been in the instructions page already, the thing is that i have problems with the first step of the six that tells you to follow. I don't know how to log in as a superuser or sudo as it tells there. It also recommends you to install CUPS and i don't know what it that also. I'm sorry, i am highly uninformed. Anyway thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, [here's an informed guide](http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=42&t=103900). I don't know if it will work (I just found it), but it seems to work everywhere.

The introduction:

> Brother's official instructions are horrible, awfully laid out, and
>   are wrong in so many places, such as suggesting that you edit
>   /etc/printcap which is an auto-generated file that you CANNOT edit
>   because any changes will automatically be replaced (herp derp), along
>   with many other plain errors; Brother's Linux people seem to be on a
>   salary of peanuts and the instructions appear to be a hobbled-together
>   mess of ancient, outdated misinformation.

Comment: Stupid brother.. I can't use scanner because of brand-new usb3. Next will be another one!