# Problems with installing Brother printer drivers.

Tags: drivers, printing, brother

I bought the Brother printer DCP-J140, and I am unable to install the printers for it. I am logged on as a the root user and everything. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

this will help

[Unable to install drivers for Linux Brother DCP-J140W printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300711/unable-to-install-drivers-for-linux-brother-dcp-j140w-printer)

I used it when installing a Brother DCP-j140 printer for a family member not to long ago.
worked for me