# Errors installing drivers for Brother DCP-J140W printer

Tags: drivers, printing, dpkg, brother

I am new Ubuntu user. My Laptop is Vaio VPCEB1M0E

I couldn't install the printer Brother DCP-J140W. I tried all the steps in these related questions and topics

- [Need help configuring Brother DCP J140W Wireless printer | Kubuntu Forums](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?61898-Need-help-configuring-Brother-DCP-J140W-Wireless-printer)
- [Linux downloads page on Brother website](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html)
- [Unable to install drivers for Linux Brother DCP-J140W printer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/300711/unable-to-install-drivers-for-linux-brother-dcp-j140w-printer)

When I did the steps in the last link  I was able to install the driver but I can't see the printer icon in the **Printers** window!

In the terminal I get this:

```
molham@molham-VPCEB1M0E:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg -i --force-all dcpj140wlpr-1.1.3-6.i386.deb
(Reading database ... 180721 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace dcpj140wlpr:i386 1.1.3-6 (using dcpj140wlpr-1.1.3-6.i386.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement dcpj140wlpr:i386 ...
Setting up dcpj140wlpr:i386 (1.1.3-6) ...
mkdir: cannot create directory `/var/spool/lpd/dcpj140w': No such file or directory
chown: cannot access `/var/spool/lpd/dcpj140w': No such file or directory
chgrp: cannot access `/var/spool/lpd/dcpj140w': No such file or directory
chmod: cannot access `/var/spool/lpd/dcpj140w': No such file or directory
```

To be honest I ignored this and continued the process:

```
molham@molham-VPCEB1M0E:~/Downloads$ sudo dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother
ii  dcpj140wlpr:i386                            1.1.3-6                                 Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions
ii  printer-driver-ptouch                       1.3-3ubuntu0.1                          printer driver Brother P-touch label printers

molham@molham-VPCEB1M0E:~$  cat /etc/printcap
DCPJ140W:\
       :mx=0:\
       :sd=/var/spool/lpd/dcpj140w:\
       :sh:\
       :lp=/dev/usb/lp0:\
       :if=/opt/brother/Printers/dcpj140w/lpd/filterdcpj140w:
```

What should I do?

Comment: I just removed the package and I'll try again !!

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problems and the printer/scanner DCP-j140(wifi) is working well under Linux Mint 13 (Maya LTS = "Ubuntu"):

I installed it under a plain/fresh Mint installation. So first You have to remove the not working printer(s) within the system...

Then you have to download the drivers from [here on the Brother website](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html)

Select the Brother DCP-j140w drivers. The Downloads directory should then contain the following 2 deb files:

```
dcpj140wcupswrapper-1.1.3-6.i386.deb
dcpj140wlpr-1.1.3-6.i386.deb
```

Use bv/ag. the Clamtk anti-virus tool to check these .deb files against viruses or malware since you downloaded them outside the protected area. (Also use the rkhunter...)

```
sudo apt-get install clamtk
sudo apt-get install rkhunter
sudo rkhunter --update
sudo rkhunter --propupd
```

and scan with

```
sudo rkhunter --check --sk
```

Probably `rkhunter` will react with some false positives, so don't panic. Check them out by searching online. This is my rkhunter result:

```
System checks summary
=====================

File properties checks...
    Files checked: 139
    Suspect files: 1

Rootkit checks...
    Rootkits checked : 245
    Possible rootkits: 0

Applications checks...
    All checks skipped

The system checks took: 1 minute and 55 seconds

All results have been written to the log file (/var/log/rkhunter.log)

One or more warnings have been found while checking the system.
Please check the log file (/var/log/rkhunter.log)
```

Look at this result: `Possible rootkits: 0`. It always should be zero. If it is not zero then you've got a serious problem. You have to shutdown and install Linux "fresh" again.

Then start a console, the "DOS"-enviroment of Linux...
From here copy/paste all letterly:

```
sudo apt-get install tcsh
cd Downloads
sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd
sudo dpkg -i --force-all dcpj140wlpr-1.1.3-6.i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i --force-all dcpj140wcupswrapper-1.1.3-6.i386.deb
```

Linux/Mint/Ubuntu installed the USB-version of the DCP-j140w.
With:

```
dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother
```

You should get output like this:

```
ii  dcpj140wcupswrapper                   1.1.3-6                                             Brother CUPS Inkjet Printer Definitions

ii  dcpj140wlpr                           1.1.3-6                                             Brother lpr Inkjet Printer Definitions

ii  printer-driver-ptouch                 1.3-3ubuntu0.1                                      printer driver Brother P-touch label printers
```

Go to **System > Hardware > Printer-configuration**:

And you see the usb-version of the DCP-j140w installed.
In the URI you see the USB-link...

If this printer was working well under Windows/Android, it should work under Linux as well...

Go to **New Printer** and wait until You see something like this:

dnssd://Brother%20DCP-J140W._printer._tcp.local/

Select that one and delete the all the previous versions of the J140W.

After that select printing a testpage:

Within Wifi it should print an Ubuntu testpage...

And now the scanner:

You have to download the scanner .deb files first from [here on the Brother website](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html)

Find them in the Downloads dir, named as:

```
brscan4-0.4.2-1.i386.deb
brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb
```

Again, they are downloaded out of the secured environment. Check them first.

I can't say this often enough: on the internet trust nobody, only yourself.

You may need to install the xsane package:

```
sudo apt-get install xsane
```

Then type:

```
sudo dpkg -i brscan4-0.4.2-1.i386.deb
sudo dpkg  -i  --force-all brscan-skey-0.2.4-1.i386.deb
```

To check out:

```
dpkg  -l  |  grep  Brother
brscan-skey
```

Then we have to find out the IP-address of our printer. Therefore we install this:

```
sudo apt-get install nmap zenmap
```

To check out: `sudo nmap 192.168.1.*`

Look for the ip-address in an item like: `xxx/tcp  open  printer`. That's the right one. Note that ip-address.

Or use  Zenmap (in root/sudo:)

If we know the ip-address of the printer we finally end with:

```
brsaneconfig4 -a name=SCANNER model=DCP-j140w ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

(Where xxx = the ip-address of the printer.

Starting up Xsane should now work properly.

Enjoy working with your Wifi printer/scanner.

Comment: Thank you I was able to install the Printer and the scanner already but the information that you gave regarding the anti virus and the rootkits was very helpful

Answer (score 2):

I came here from google looking for solutions for similar error messages like yours:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/var/spool/lpd/hl3152cdw’: No such file or directory
chown: cannot create directory ‘/var/spool/lpd/hl3152cdw’: No such file or directory
...
```

In my case I could solve it by simply creating the mentioned directories:

```
$ sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd
$ sudo mkdir /var/spool/lpd/hl3152cdw
```

Just replace `hl3152cdw` with your printer name mentioned in the error message.

Reference: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers/BrotherMFC-240CPrinter

Answer (score 0):

Good guide man ;)
But if you printer is wifi !!
This should be an address of it:

dnssd://Brother%20DCP-J140W._printer._tcp.local/

And drivers are here, rest is ok ;)

http://support.brother.com/g/s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html

Answer (score 0):

I installed the drivers for printer and scanner (DCP-J140W) but I could not manage to scan over wifi (printer worked fine over wifi). However, I changed the IP of the printer, reinstalled the drivers and now everything works like a charm.

Regards